# Neo4j Creating relationships from JSON data based on position in nested list

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I have some data in a JSON file:

```
{"title": "Title1", "authors": [{"name": "John Mulaney", "org": "Stanford"}, {"name": "Dave Chappelle", "org": "MIT"}, {"name": "Kurt Warner", "org": "UCSB"}, {"name": "Hulk Hogan", "org": "UCSD"}], "id": "abc123"}
{"title": "Title2", "authors": [{"name": "Rick Sanchez", "org": "MIT"}, {"name": "Amy Schumer", "org": "Harvard"}], "id": "xyz234"}
```

Specifically, I would like to add a property to each of the relationships between author and paper that corresponds to the authors position in the author list - where the property looks like 
`"position":"first_author", "position":"second_author", etc and the last author is "position":"last_author".`

There are a variable number of authors in each paper.

The following Cypher command creates nodes for the papers and authors, and creates relationships between them.

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.id AS id UNWIND q.authors as authors 
MERGE (a:Author {name:authors.name})
MERGE (p:Paper {id:q.id}) ON CREATE SET p.title=q.title
CREATE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(p)
```

How can I keep track of the position in the author list and add this as a property to the relationship when there are a variable number of authors?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to optimized a little your query, I prefer to put the `MERGE` of the `Paper` outside the loop for the `Author` :

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q 
UNWIND q.id AS id 
  MERGE (p:Paper {id:q.id}) ON CREATE SET p.title=q.title
    WITH p, q
      UNWIND q.authors as authors 
        MERGE (a:Author {name:authors.name})
        CREATE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(p)
```

To respond to your question, you need to create the index of the author position. To do this I will use the : `range(0, size(q.authors), 1) AS index`.

As an example, `RETURN range(0, 10, 1) AS index` give this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

At the end, this is the searched query :

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q 
UNWIND q.id AS id 
  MERGE (p:Paper {id:q.id}) ON CREATE SET p.title=q.title
    WITH p, q, range(0, size(q.authors), 1) AS indexes 
      UNWIND indexes as index
        MERGE (a:Author {name:q.authors[index].name})
        CREATE (a)-[:AUTHORED {order:index}]->(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I tried the 2nd query, I got an error `Expected a numeric value for RangeFunction({  AUTOINT1},length(q.authors),{  AUTOINT2}), but got null` 
As far as I can tell, there are no empty author lists in the data, so not sure what could be causing this issue.

Comment: And what if you do `CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q  RETURN size(q.authors)` ?

Comment: It returns mostly numbers, but also includes a few null values.